# unable to send message from client to server

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a client server program that server is multi thread , The code compile without any error, but it doesn't show any message from client.
 just it run up to the "qDebug() << " Client connected";"
Here is my code .I would be grateful if you can say where is the problem.

myclient.cpp

```
#include "myclient.h"
#include "QTcpsocket"
#include "QTcpServer"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "QHostAddress"



myclient::myclient(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
}

void myclient::start(QString address, quint16 port)
  {

       QHostAddress LocalHost;
       LocalHost.setAddress(address);

        m_client.connectToHost(LocalHost, 6666);

        QObject::connect(&m_client, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(startTransfer()));

   }

void myclient::startTransfer()
{
  m_client.write("Hello", 5);
}
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "myserver.h"

mythread::mythread(QTcpSocket*, QObject *parent) :

QThread(parent)
{
}

void mythread::run()
{

  qDebug() << " Thread started";

    if (m_client)

  {
  connect(m_client, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
  }


 qDebug() << " Client connected";

     exec();
  }


void mythread::readyRead()

{
  QByteArray Data = m_client->readAll();

  qDebug()<< " Data in: " << Data;

  m_client->write(Data);
}


void mythread::disconnected()
{
  qDebug() << " Disconnected";

  m_client->deleteLater();

  exit(0);
}
```

myserver.cpp

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"


myserver::myserver(QObject *parent) :

QObject(parent)
{
}

void myserver::startserver()
{

  connect(&m_server,SIGNAL(newConnection()), this ,SLOT(newConnection()));

  int port = 6666;

  if(m_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))

  {        
    qDebug() << "Listening to port " ;
  }

 else
  {
    qDebug() << "Could not start server "<<m_server.errorString();
  }
  }


void myserver::newConnection()
{

 m_client = m_server.nextPendingConnection();

 qDebug() << " Connecting...";

 mythread *thread = new mythread(m_client,this);

 thread->start();

}
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34248702/edit) your question and add codes of your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection) about `nextPendingConnection()` says:

> Note: The returned QTcpSocket object cannot be used from another
>   thread. If you want to use an incoming connection from another thread,
>   you need to override incomingConnection().

So, you can't use that socket in another thread. As the docs say, you can subclass `QTcpServer` and override `incomingConnection()`, this method is invoked whenever a client tries to connect to your server.

`incomingConnection()` method provides a socket descriptor (just like regular file descriptors). And then you can pass that socket descriptor to another thread and create the `QTcpSocket` completely over there.

Inside that thread, you would need something like this:

```
QTcpSocket client = new QTcpSocket();
client.setSocketDescriptor(sockId);

// Now, you can use this socket as a connected socket.
// Make sure to connect its ready read signal to your local slot.
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Once you get in `newConnection` the client is already connected, and you just need to start a thread that calls `readAll` and then replies.</strike>

There's no need to wait for a `connected()` signal again.

### EDIT

The `QSocket` class is designed to work asynchronously on the main thread, based on events. From the documentation:

> Warning: QSocket is not suitable for use in threads. If you need to uses sockets in threads use the lower-level QSocketDevice class.

Comment: i ignore the connected() but still it doesn't work! i get the following error when run server :The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Ooh, you're right, we can't use that socket inside a background thread. It'll throw an exception.

Comment: @Hanita: Sorry. I based my reply on general socket programming techniques. `QSocket` is an higher-level object with a completely different approach... you should refer to the documentation for an example client/server solution (e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html)